Folder Specific Docker Volumes
I used docker compose to create several docker containers with volumes. Now the containers are ready and I would like to export them so they can be used.
Yet this is not working out properly as the volumes seem to be created/dependent on the folders docker compose up is executed in.
Originally I have started the docker-compose.yml from a folder called mop which is also a mounted volume for one of the docker containers. I have used docker commit to save the state of the containers.
I copied the docker-compose.yml to a different folder (named docker) and added the image-tag with the created containers obtained from the commit.
However, the volumes are reset and empty. None of the dockers are using the volumes from the setup. Apparently new docker volumes were created depending on the folder I am using:
> docker volume ls 
local    d123...
local    docker_artifactory-datavolume
local    docker_jenkins-datavolume
local    docker_mop_vol
local    docker_pgdata
local    e543...
local    mop_artifactory-datavolume
local    mop_jenkins-datavolume
local    mop_pgdata
local    mop_vol
local    sharedfolder_artifactory-datavolume
local    sharedfolder_jenkins-datavolume
local    sharedfolder_pgdata

(The sharedfolder is apparently from a test run that involved only some of the images)
The (shortened) docker-compose.yml:
version: '3'
services:  
  db:
    container_name: postgreSQL
    image: postgres:14.1
    ...
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql14/data    
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin4
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    volumes:
       - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ...
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./django.Dockerfile
    command: ./entrypoint.sh 
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/djangohome
    ...
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    depends_on:
      - db
      - arangodb

  arangodb:
    image: arangodb
    ...
    volumes:
      - /opt/db-data:/var/lib/arangodb3
    networks:
      - mynetwork        
    restart: always

  arangodb_data:
    image: arango_ubuntu_backup
    ...
    volumes:
      - /opt/db-data:/var/lib/arangodb
      - /opt/arangodb/save:/var/save 

networks:
  mynetwork:
volumes:
  pgdata:
    driver: local
  pgadmin:

What would be the proper way to access the specified volumes independently from the folders?

Compose has the notion of a project, and when you run the same Compose file in a different (-ly named) directory, Compose assumes you want an independent set of containers, networks, and volumes.  Which things do and don't you want to be shared?  docker commit is rarely if ever a best practice, and it doesn't seem like you need it here; what have you committed, and why?

@DavidMaze - I have successfully created a copy of the running containers by using commit and then export. (Or at least I think I did). My idea was to also to export the volumes and provide a set of a working network of dockers with their data which is equivalent to what is running on my machine.
While the docker containers were running I used commit on them and then export on the newly created image. As from my information commit creates an image without the mounted folders I assumed providing the volumes separately is the way to go?

Committing an image doesn't include any changes in mounted volumes of any sort.  You should never need to commit images or to export container filesystems.  If you can copy the data from one project to the other, then running the original unmodified images should have the same behavior.

@DavidMaze - how would I copy the entire docker data to another?

Copy docker volumes describes a couple of procedures.  You need to create the volumes, then mount both the old and new volumes into a container running cp -a.  This is a place where bind-mounted host directories can be easier to manage than Docker named volumes.
